# Accessing NSWindow.level for all applications windows on screen

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-graphics, accessibility

I am trying to manipulate the windows of macOS. I have found the following URLs:

- [Move other windows on Mac OS X using Accessibility API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069066/move-other-windows-on-mac-os-x-using-accessibility-api)
- [Getting Window Number through OSX Accessibility API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178860/getting-window-number-through-osx-accessibility-api/6365105) (Core Graphics)
- [set the size and position of all windows on the screen in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47480873/set-the-size-and-position-of-all-windows-on-the-screen-in-swift)
- [How to set an external application always being frontmost on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630324/how-to-set-an-external-application-always-being-frontmost-on-os-x) (Unanswered)
- [How to convert a Carbon AXUIElementRef to Cocoa NSWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642999/how-to-convert-a-carbon-axuielementref-to-cocoa-nswindow) (Unanswered)
- [Setting the window level over Accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824519/setting-the-window-level-over-accessibility) (Unanswered)
- [How to create an AXUIElementRef from an NSView or NSWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906540/how-to-create-an-axuielementref-from-an-nsview-or-nswindow) (Unanswered)

The links allow for accessing the various windows of an application via the Accessibility API of macOS; more specifically, they use the `AXUIElementRef` element to re-position windows.

When creating an app for macOS, I have successfully used the following code ...

```
@implementation CustomWindow

- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSWindowStyleMask)windowStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)deferCreation
{
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:windowStyle backing:bufferingType defer:deferCreation];
    if(self)
    {
        [self setLevel:kCGDesktopWindowLevel - 1];
        [self setCollectionBehavior:
         (NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces |
          NSWindowCollectionBehaviorStationary |
          NSWindowCollectionBehaviorIgnoresCycle)];
    }
    return self;
}

// ...

@end
```

... to put a window on the Desktop level of the screen. What I am looking for is a way to manipulate the same Window level property or the like via a custom Windows Manager application. In other words, I would like to code a windows manager that can manipulate the levels the windows of other applications on screen.

Am, I correct in my findings that this can't be done? Can it be done via Core Graphics?

In addition, I want to change the application that is key and in focus, but I think this can be done.

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: @m.gansrigler I had to do a work around, so no. =(

Comment: @PLG Any news on this topic?

Comment: @LeadDeveloper I haven't heard of Apple changing APIs on this, but I haven't been actively searching either.

Comment: Any progress with this? I am keen to know your workaround. I too want to control the window level of other app's windows but can't seem to find a relevant API.

Comment: @RamPatra Unless Apple creates the API in the Accessibility API, I don't think it exists. It would be interesting if we could contact Apple and ask them to add the functionality to the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really manipulate the `CGWindowLevel` of a window (all normal windows are `kCGNormalWindowLevel`, for example) but if you're looking to change the order of a normal-level window relative to others then you're probably looking for Accessibility's [`kAXRaiseAction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/kaxraiseaction?language=objc), which you can [see in action here](https://github.com/numist/Haxcessibility/blob/trunk/Classes/HAXWindow.m#L27-L44).

If you're just looking to see what all the windows on the system are (and their `CGWindowLevel`s, then [`CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455137-cgwindowlistcopywindowinfo) will give you that information.

Comment: I assumed it was not possible to manipulate, since I didn't get an answer for 2 years. I was specifically looking for a way to put a window on Desktop level. Thanks for your answer though. Your link to `kAXRaiseAction` might come in handy later.